# learning objective-c with Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, app-store

I am a PHP developer, and want to learn objective-c usage withing its well known IDE - XCode to start building IOS apps for iphone and then sell them on AppStore.
my questions are:

1. What's the best (and easiest) documentation to start with ?
2. Is it that easy for me (as a beginner objective-c developer) to attract customers on AppStore and get them to buy my IOS apps, or is there a huge competition among experts on AppStore so that there is no chance for beginners on AppStore?
3. If there is any chance to sell my apps on AppStore, what's the possible profit for them on AppStore ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's the best (and easiest) documentation to start with?

I found this link (for PHP programmers):
http://mohrt.blogspot.com/2008/10/objective-c-crash-course-for-php.html
Otherwise go with books, and use xCode and read code.

Learn **Objective - C**: (Programming Objective C 2.0) - [http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Objective-C-2-0-Stephen-Kochan/dp/0321566157/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1298891453&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321566157)

Learn **iOS coding**: (Big Nerd Ranch) [http://www.amazon.com/iPhone-Programming-Ranch-Guide-Guides/dp/0321706242/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1298891484&sr=1-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321706242)

> Is it that easy for me (as a beginner objective-c developer) to attract
>    customers on AppStore and get them to buy my IOS apps, or is there a huge
>    competition among experts on AppStore so that there is no chance for
>    beginners on AppStore?

If your idea is good and your app is well written sure. But there are a few competitors.

> If there is any chance to sell my apps on AppStore, what's the possible profit for them on AppStore ?

There is no easy answer to your question here, but you will have a profit from apple with 70% of the product prize.

Good luck out there.

Answer (score 0):

I have learned IOS programming using big nerd ranch guide. It is very nice, updated (this is important because the development environment keeps changing) has lots of good examples and most importantly teach you each concept by making you write the code itself. Following it throughly will result shortly.

Writing an attractive app is a different issue. But if you improve yourself in UI design a little bit, tackle the challenges of the mobile environment and provide functionality &  stability to your app, you will have a chance to shine. But I do not like the idea of trying to create an app which profits well. Build an app with good quality and make people willing to support your work instead; profit should be a result, not the aim.

Answer (score 0):

In response to your questions:

1. The best (and easiest) documentation to start with is definitely Big Nerd Ranch's Objective-C Programming for beginners.  It may seem overwhelming at the beginning but if you're able to plug away at server side languages day after day then you will eventually grasp objective-c very well.  Also recommend watching Stanford University's iOS videos on youtube in your down time to become more familiar with the terminology while learning the language.

   2. It seems the app store is no different from doing a website Google search for results, so you may want to consider marketing initiatives to get your app up-voted in order to become recommended by others or possibly just grow your download numbers.  This answer is purely subjective.
   3. Depends purely on your marketing efforts to grow interest.